# How do you update only one field via a Web Api in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I´m using Asp.net and Web Api 2.

Say I have a `Client` object with four fields: `UniqueId`, `Name`, `Email` and `PhoneNumber`. Whenever a user updates the phone number in the front end I don´t want to send back to the server the whole object with 2 unchanged fields (`Name` and `Email`) and only one changed field (`PhoneNumber`). I'm not counting `UniqueId` because that never changes and always has to go back and forth to the server.

The best solution I've found so far is to **send the unchanged fields empty**, and so the Api only updates the non-empty fields. But this **forbids storing empty values** in the Database, which is in general not desirable.

Could any one provide with some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: can you show an example of code in regards to what you currently have..? sounds like you need to send all fields for your update or change the database to allow for Null values.. then you will need to write some better validation code for first time entries also how can you show us the code please so that we can get a better visual understanding of what you are trying to do..

Comment: Instead of sending a `Client` object, you can have a change object containing the Unique ID and a changes array field that hold field key and value pairs. Or if you would rather still keep sending a `Client` object, add an array field that will contain only the name of the keys that have been changed. But really, if your data object is so small, it doesn't make a big difference and it is easier to just send it all for code clarity and debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just usually create an object with the fields needed.  In your example, I would just send an object:

```
{"UniqueId": 4, "PhoneNumber": "SOME NUMBER"}
```

Web Api will fill in the missing properties with their default values.